# System.FormatException: 'Could not parse the JSON file. Error while debugging on .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

Getting this error only while debugging but no errors while building

> System.FormatException
> HResult=0x80131537
>   `Message=Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '2': '{ {'. Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions StackTrace: at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload) at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load() at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
> at ReverseProxyApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\av\Downloads\netcore2-reverse-proxy-master\netcore2-reverse-proxy-master\ReverseProxyApplication\Program.cs:line 17
> `
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
JsonReaderException: Invalid property identifier character: {. Path '', line 2, position 2.

This is my launchSettings.json :

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ReverseProxyApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080/"
    }
  },
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57068",
      "sslPort": 44388
    }
  }
}
```

This is my program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ReverseProxyApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

This is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MyAPI": {
    "ApiKey": "abcde123454"
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace ReverseProxyApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Load API key from configuration
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

            // Load API key from configuration
            string apiKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("MyAPI:ApiKey");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("API key is missing or empty.");
            }

            // Register the API key as a configuration option
            services.Configure<ApiOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ApiKey = apiKey;
            });

            // ...
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMiddleware<ReverseProxyMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

Any Idea what's wrong with this??

I tried Encoding launchSettings.json to be encoded with utf-8-BOM and tried validating it everything looks fine but still getting this error.

Comment: Please care for a proper formatting of your post. In its current state it's rather hard to read ... And please post code as text and not as image ...

Comment: What about your `appsettings.json` files?

Comment: This is my appsettings.json


{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MyAPI": {
    "ApiKey": "abcde123454"
  }
}

Comment: @derpirscher Updated the formatting please have a look into it now

Comment: Launchsettings is something of visual studio, and is not used by your application. the fault won't be there. It will be in appsettings.json. It seems to be valid json what you posted. Is there another appsettings.json file it is trying to load? perhaps appsettings.<environment>.json files that fault?

Comment: The JSON looks valid on first sight. But there *might* be something like an invalid whitespace, because strictly speaking for instance a `tab` is not allowed as whitespace JSON and very strict parsers may throw errors. And maybe you can further inspect your exception to verify it's really that particular `appsettings.json` file (check the full path if you can find it) that is causing the error.

Comment: @akashram you can actually bind your Options class directly to your configuration
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#bind-hierarchical-configuration
Doesn't help with your current problem but would save you some boilerplate and validation.

Comment: Do you have any user secrets setup for your project? or any env specific appsettings? e.g. appsettings.development.json or appsettings.local.json.